# Alternative to "How do I make a person do Y?" and "How do I get a person to do Y?"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

"How do I make a person do ... ?" and "How do I get a person to do ... ?" are colloquial.

I've considered these, but they don't have the same meaning:

- "How do I force a person to do ... ?"
- "How do I encourage a person to do ... ?"

What're some same-meaning alternatives to "make someone do something" and "get someone to do something"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be noted that *get* and *make* have subtly different meanings.

*Make* often implies some level of force or coercion, while *get* leaves the door open to persuasion.

---

How do I *make* a person do ... =

- How do I [*compel*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/compel) a person to do ...

> to force or drive, especially to a course of action:

---

How do I *get* a person to do ... =

- How do I [*induce*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/induce) a person to do ...

> to move by persuasion or influence